# wait() для AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

У меня есть активность и `AsyncTask`. Чтобы сохранить `AsyncTask` без изменений, если повернется экран (на случай, если экран повернут во время загрузки из БД, которая идет в цикле, я "усыпляю" `AsyncTask`, чтобы цикл ждал возобновления). Но когда я вызываю `loadData.wait()` — засыпает `Activity`! Как это исправить, а главное почему — это происходит?

Вот код (из лога видно, что выполнение дальше `wait()` не идет):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    private LoadData loadData;

    @Override
    public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
        loadData.unLink();

        synchronized (loadData) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, MSG + "До wait()");
                loadData.wait();
                Log.i(TAG, MSG + "После wait()");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, MSG + "ERROR!!! + " + e);
            }
        }

        return loadData;
    }

    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> {

        ...
        ...
        ...

        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = null;

        LoadData(String name) {

            ...
            ...
            ...

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            ...
            ...
            ...

        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ...
            ...
            ...

            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void ... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            ...
            ...
            ...

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ...
            ...
            ...

        }

        void link(MainActivity act) {
            mainActivity = act;
        }

        void unLink() {
            mainActivity = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем вас не устраивает [решение](http://startofandroid.com/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana.html) задачи по первой ссылке гугла на запрос

> [asynctask поворот экрана](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asynctask%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

?

А засыпает ваша активити потому, что объект loadData является полем активити и установка блокировки на него, видать, усыпляет и активити, т.к. и активити и loadData находятся в одном потоке и только doInBackground - в другом.

Comment: Вам тут вообще все эти синхронизации ни к чему.

Comment: Тут поток сохраняется, но не останавливается, так что такое решение подходит не полностью.

Comment: Ну сделайте тогда вообще отдельный поток в сервисе вместо асинктаска. Полный контроль будет обеспечен

Comment: А серисы умеют работать с UI? Я в `onUpdate` взаимодействую с `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: А хотя... Идея! Нужно попробовать способ, который я еще у Шилдта прочитал (а раньше думал, что ничего не понял...) - использовать флаги. Через метод я буду устанавливать переменную и, при каждом обороте цикла, еси она `true`, усыплять `doInBackground`. Правда как будить его... Или получить ссылку на `doInBackground ` и будить ее (но не уверен, что так можно), или использовать `notifyAll`.